# Illustrator space under text line

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I can't seem to get the handle of this text that i want to align with the red rectangle in the back, the only solution i have is to make the text an outline and align it after that, but i have some different text that i want to edit with more rectangles, so it's not what i need.
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sadly an irritating thing that's hidden away, and set up to a stupid default in Illustrator. Rather than messing around with baseline points, you can tell it to align text bjects with respect to the glyph bounds, rather than the bounding box.

Adobe have a breif explainer of this here (https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/align-text.html) , but within the text alignment menu go to to More Options flyout (three buttons) , and the next "more options" and select Align to Glyph Bounds". Point Text or Area text works fine  [image: Align glyphs...]

Enjoy.

Answer (score 3):

Adjust the baseline shift by choosing a negative number. A baseline is a line that the text rests on.

[image: baseline shift example]

Fonts are going to have different x-height or capital heights, etc. This will change the surrounding box based on how the font was made. You will need to adjusted the baseline depending on the font. Illustrator will vertically align the text based on the surrounding box.

Comment: So, i guess it's not working like in CorelDRAW where if you don;t have in your text a lower character it will center correct

Comment: @speeder Correct, Illustrator centers the text frame, not based on the actual letters.